# set second x axis zero position

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot with second x-axis on top of my chart. How can I shift the zero position of this second axis on a specific value? I want the 0 position of the second x-axis to correspond with the value 2.13 of my primary x-axis. for the second x-axis I used

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twiny()
```

and I read the values for second x axis from a list called epsilon.

```
def tick_function(X):
    return ["%.4f" % z for z in X]

ax2.set_xticklabels(tick_function(epsilon))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to set the bound for the second x axes:

[image]

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

x1 = [2.13, 2.135, 2.139, 2.14, 2.143]
y1 = range(len(x1))

x2 = [0, 100, 200, 350, 450]

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(x1, y1)
ax1.grid(True)

ax2 = ax1.twiny()

ax2.set_xticks(x1)
ax2.set_xbound(ax1.get_xbound())
ax2.set_xticklabels(x2)

fig.savefig("15.png")
```

Comment: yes, it is thank you, but the range on the top x-axis is in my case totally different from the bottom one. the bottom one is 2.1 - 2.4 and on the top I want to visualize only 5 values at specific positions ranging from 0 to 450 (at specific nonlinear positions, say at 2.13 the value 0, at 2.135 value 100, at 2.139 200, at 2.14 350 and at 2.143 450). It's a bit complicated.

Comment: @user3041107: now it is much clearer. You should really have given a complete data in You original post.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, this is what I needed. Sorry for the misunderstanding.